# What is correct resolution for background image in cordova application

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova

I am developing a cordova application. Its having different back ground image for different screens. We had given the background image in different resolution in media query. But now the background image is not showing in different resolutions. Can you please suggest a method to resolve this issue. What are the correct resolution for setting the background image. We are stuck with this issue.  Can you please provide us a solution

Answer (score 0):

you can use image as background in CSS like

```
body{
    background-image:url('your_url');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

this way image fill background and 
    flag

Any resolution will work, the image will be either zoomed in or out if needed.

Answer (score 0):

place your image inside a div
 then define the following style. So Background Image will Scaleg While Maintaining Aspect Ratio

```
div {
    position    : absolute;
    top         : 0px;
    left        : 0px;
    overflow    : hidden;
    width       : 100%;
    height      : 100%;
    font-weight : bold;
    font-size   : 30px;
}
```